# SmartGwt DataSource field for Long type Variable

Tags: smartgwt

One of my property which i want to populate in list grid is of Long type. I am populating my list grid with the data source . But, we dont have any grid field Long type api in smartgwt. plss help me out . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DataSourceIntegerField](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/fields/DataSourceIntegerField.html) works with *[integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer)* of any length, including Java's Longs. Yes, the naming is confusing.